# Creating a type-aware constructor method

Tags: typescript

I have a situation where there exists a set of types: `A`, `B`, and `C`. Each extending the same common interface `I`. I would like to be able to express a method like so:

```
class SomeClass {
    private somenumber = 1;
    private someproperty;

    addThing(cls: {new(number): I}) {
        var instance = new cls(this.somenumber);
        instance.someSharedOperation(this.someproperty);
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Essentially I need a constructor method which will associate the generated instance with data specific to the instance which created it.

I would then call it like so:

```
var maker = new SomeClass();
instanceA = maker.addThing(A);
```

The above of course works, but TypeScript considers `instanceA` to be of type `I`. I would like it to reflect the original type `A` while restricting `cls` to an implementation of `I`. But I admit that this might be too far into "dependent type"-land to be expressible in TypeScript, even though the type *could* be mechanistically determined.

Answer (score 1):

Of course writing all of that out made it instantly clear what was wrong:

Solution was to state that `new` would return an extension of `I`:

```
addThing<E extends I>(cls: {new(number): E}): E {
    var instance = new cls(this.somenumber);
    instance.someSharedOperation(this.someproperty);
    return instance;
}
```

Pretty straight-forward!